# Ruby193 completely ignore breakpoints in debug mode

Tags: debugging, ruby-on-rails-3.2, netbeans-6.9

I had just upgrade from Ruby192 to Ruby193 (rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p392).

After gone through many errors and googling, I manage to start up the server normally without any error.

When I start up my server with debug mode (In NetBeans 6.9.1) it just ignore the breakpoints and continue to load the page, see below output.

```
Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.17.beta16, ruby-debug-base19x 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:49628
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.12 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2013-03-09 11:34:54] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2013-03-09 11:34:54] INFO  ruby 1.9.3 (2013-02-22) [i386-mingw32]
[2013-03-09 11:34:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=708 port=3000
Breakpoint 32 at D:/MyWorkspace/NetBeans_Projects/homeloqsg/app/controllers/miscellaneous_controller.rb:7
```

I have the following gem installed

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.2.12)
actionpack (3.2.12)
activemodel (3.2.12)
activerecord (3.2.12)
activeresource (3.2.12)
activesupport (3.2.12)
addressable (2.3.3)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (3.0.2)
authlogic (3.2.0)
aws-s3 (0.6.3)
aws-sdk (1.8.3.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bson (1.8.3)
bson_ext (1.8.3)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.1)
carrierwave (0.8.0)
climate_control (0.0.3)
cocaine (0.5.1)
columnize (0.3.6)
debugger (1.4.0)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
excon (0.16.10)
fog (1.10.0)
formatador (0.2.4)
gmaps4rails (1.5.6)
heroku (2.35.0)
heroku-api (0.3.8)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.4)
io-console (0.3)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.2.1)
json (1.5.5)
launchy (2.2.0)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.4.4)
mime-types (1.21)
minitest (2.5.1)
multi_json (1.6.1)
mysql (2.8.1 x86-mingw32)
net-scp (1.1.0)
net-ssh (2.6.6)
netrc (0.7.7)
nokogiri (1.5.6 x86-mingw32)
paperclip (3.4.1)
pg (0.14.1 x86-mingw32)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.5)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.3)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.12)
railties (3.2.12)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdiscount (1.6.8)
rdoc (3.9.5)
rest-client (1.6.7)
rmagick (2.13.2)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta16)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (2.0.1)
rubyzip (0.9.9)
sitemap_generator (3.4)
sprockets (2.2.2)
thor (0.17.0)
tilt (1.3.4)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.36)
uuidtools (2.1.3)
will_paginate (3.0.4)
xml-simple (1.1.2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggled for hours I manage to solved this issue.

I think I have too many debug gems.

```
debugger (1.4.0)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.0)
ruby-debug-base19x (0.11.30.pre10)
ruby-debug-ide (0.4.17.beta16)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
```

After removed the following gems it working fine and the breakpoints just stop at the line I want.

```
debugger (1.4.0)
debugger-linecache (1.1.2)
debugger-ruby_core_source (1.2.0)
```

Thanks.